# PHP load user data file

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

This seems like a simple question...I am trying to allow users to 'load' a saved data file with a Load button, choose file, etc. Can I read the data file directly into a variable from their file or does it need to be uploaded to the server first then opened and read closed and then unlinked?

Thank you,
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because PHP is SERVERSIDE you can't do anything without uploading the file. Unless this file already is on the server, there is no way around this problem.

I `prettier` way of doing it could be to use a jQuery-plugin to upload the file (without the page getting refreshed) and then access the content using `ajax`

Comment: Of course! I am already using ajaxUpload. Thank you. Just for the record, it is not really a problem to do it the php way...as you said just not as elegant. Have a great day.

Comment: Well, if you use an uploader and the file is located on your server, there is no problem in reading it. Simply do some ajax-magic ;) Good day to you too.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be uploaded for PHP to access it, unless the file's contents are sent via JavaScript to PHP. [That relies on a cutting edge browser](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: @Yuri You could have provisions for the user to paste the file's contents. If it were an image you could send the pixel data, dependent on if it's available.

Comment: Do you suggest the user to put file content in form manually? For god sake, is it a joke?

Comment: @Yuri If it's text, it's an option, and I've seen it done many places.

Comment: And if it is text, but for about 10 000 lines? And if the user does not quite common with copy-paste operation (a lot of people don't)? And how often do you have to put some plain text files on any website, not pictures, pdf or binaries? Come on, it is not an option?

Comment: @Yuri I said it's *one* way, not the best or preferred way. Is your constant arguing a joke?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to upload the file first because you have no access to the user's filesystem through browser neither using PHP nor JavaScript.